# batch move/cut folders and its content to another folder

Tags: windows, command-line, shell-script

I have this batch script that allows me to copy folders and its content from a text file, could someone help me adjust it so it move/cut the folders+content and not just copy?

```
  set file_list=ready.txt
    set dest_folder=c:\small\final
    for /f "delims=" %%a in (%file_list%) do (
    xcopy /Y "%%a*" "%dest_folder%%%~pa"
    )
```

Comment: All you need is to change `xcopy ...` to `move ...`.  Look at `move /?` for specifics.

Comment: I tried that, it gives me an error "Cannot move multiple files to a single file."

Comment: That is one of the things you should have posted in your original question.  In the future, be sure to include all relevant information (i.e. the problem, things you tried, what errors you saw, etc.) and update your question with things like that.  Glad you got this answered, welcome to Super User!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note: you can't use wildcards with `move`.

(and please make `file_list` -> `dir_list` for clarity.)

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set dir_list=ready.txt
set dest_folder=c:\small\final\ok
mkdir %dest_folder%
for /f "delims=" %%a IN (%dir_list%) do (
   set dir=%%a
   if "!dir:~-1!"=="\" set dir=!dir:~0,-1!
   move "!dir!" "%dest_folder%\"
)
```

For directories in `ready.txt` with trailing `\` the `\` will be removed before the `move`.

---

**Edit**:

Since you are moving the directories from one drive to another you **can't** use `move`. Here is a solution with `robocopy`:

```
@echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set dir_list=ready.txt
set dest_folder=d:\small\final\ok\
if "%dest_folder:~-1%"=="\" set dest_folder=%dest_folder:~0,-1%
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%dir_list%) do (
  set dir1=%%a
  if "!dir1:~-1!"=="\" set dir1=!dir1:~0,-1!
  for %%f in (!dir1!) do set dir2=%%~nxf
  robocopy "!dir1!" "%dest_folder%\!dir2!" /MOVE /E
)
```

Please note `robocopy` can only copy and move entire directories and not single files. So your `ready.txt` should only consists of directories. Trailing `\` are taken care of and can be mixed.

`Robocopy` needs the complete directory name for the new directory, that's why we need the
`for %%f`-line (to get te last directory-part of the source-directory.) So it needs
`robocopy c:\sub\meme d:\sub\meme`. You can't do `robocopy c:\sub\meme d:\sub`.

You can test this batchfile by putting `echo` before the `robocopy`-file
(and before the `move` in the previous example).

Comment: Was your first sentence intended to be *can't* use wildcards? Also, the safer thing to do is `mkdir` the destination first, and add a backslash (`\`) to the end of the folder name (e.g. `%dest_folder%\`). The `mkdir` will create it if it doesn't exist, and the backslash means it will either move into the directory or throw an error (if not exist) - rather than renaming anything.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt however That didn't work, i get The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @Bob Yes, tnx. I forgot 2 characters. (Also added the `mkdir`.) About the `\ `. It depends... if the directory is successfully created a `\ ` wouldn't be necessary. And if the `%dest_folder%` is changed to include the `\ ` all goes wrong. (I'll add it with a warning)

Comment: @user2827759 Could you change the line `move xxx` to `echo move xxx` and post the result in your answer (via [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/683384/edit)). We don't have all the files (e.g. we don't know what you have in `ready.txt`).

Comment: @Rik Doubled up backslashes shouldn't matter - the system will treat any number of consecutive backslashes the same as a single one. Yea, it's not strictly necessary after `mkdir`, but it also doesn't hurt ;)

Comment: @Bob Yup. I see it now. It does. Thnx.

Comment: @user2827759 The directories in your `ready.txt` should **not** include a trailing `\ `. Otherwise you get the error `The system cannot find the file specified.`.

Comment: this is the output i'm getting `C:\small>(echo move "E:\Work 2013\projects\elements\" "c:\small\final" )
move "E:\Work 2013\elements\" "c:\small\final"`  in the text file i have one path `E:\Work 2013\Scrap projects\elements\`

Comment: As i said: The directories in your `ready.txt` should **not** include a trailing `\ `. But i'll change my answer shortly to delete any trailing `\ `.

Comment: i removed the trailing \ now its giving me `access is denied` tried rebooting in case the folders were open elsewhere and ran cmd as admin without luck.

Comment: You **can't** `move` directories from one drive to another (which you are trying to do). I'll post a solution with `robocopy` later. What version of Windows do you use?

Comment: tried your last answer and it simply created a folder "ok" in the dest folder

Comment: ah ok, yes i'm trying to move it from two differen't drives, ill try to move it on the same drive and get back. i'm using windows 8. @Rik Edited: tried on the same drive however i'm getting syntax error with your last answer.

Comment: @user2827759 I added the method with `robocopy`. It should be present in Windows 8 by default.

Comment: I also changed the original batchfile for `move`. (i made an error with `!dir!`. But now they are both correct. You can use the first for `move` within a drive and the second for `robocopy` between drives.

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you very much your time. anyway i can buy you a coffee? paypal maybe?

Comment: Not necessary. Glad i could help. You may help the next one :)